# Installing bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 via npm installs the wrong version

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install

My package.json file has `bootstrap: ^4.0.0-alpha.6` specified, yet when I run `npm install` I get `...alpha.4` installed. Anyone know why I am getting a lower version installed?

Comment: slightly off-topic a little but I would recommend moving to Bootstrap's Beta release.

Comment: I will for future projects but there are too many changes for me to upgrade this app - I am already at the point of release :)